# REST-Definition - Is a System not a RESTful System once it provides user authorization?

Tags: rest

I've started reading a bit about RESTful Systems and got to [this paper](http://tim.vanstaalduine.com/downloads/books/Packt_-_RESTful_Java_Web_Services.pdf). It says on page 7-8 there are the following restrictions for RESTful Systems:

> - It must be a client-server system
> - It has to be stateless—there should be no need for the service to keep users' sessions; in other words, each request should be
>     independent of others RESTful Architectures
> - It has to support a caching system—the network infrastructure should support cache at different levels
> - It has to be uniformly accessible—each resource must have a unique address and a valid point of access
> - It has to be layered—it must support scalability
> - It should provide code on demand—although this is an optional constraint, applications can be extendable at runtime by allowing the
>     downloading of code on demand, for example, Java Applets

Now there is point 2 that says that there should be no need for keeping the user's session. That means for me, that every application that provides a login-system is no RESTful System (per definition) because I need to keep e.g. a user-token for authenticating at the API as a user that is allowed to access this resource.

Yet, I cannot inmagine that every RESTful System does not support any security standards like e.g. authorization. Did I missunderstand that or is any system supporting authorization not a RESTful System.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Authentication does not require a stateful API.

As a straw-man example, consider an application which has:

- A configuration file containing a hard-coded username and password.
- A request format which includes the username and password in every request.
- Logic which runs whenever a request is received, and compares the request against the configuration file.

This system could run on an entirely read-only system, never storing any state at all; and yet, clearly, it has authentication.

If we move the username and password to a database, the application is still stateless - it only ever needs to read that database, not write to it. Similarly, we can transmit a hash of the password plus a nonce rather than the plaintext password, support multiple users with different permissions, etc, and we have not introduced statefulness.

If you introduce a token system such as OAuth, where the user requests a token once, and uses it for subsequent requests instead of sending their full credentials, you are potentially introducing state - storing the valid token and checking it on each request. This isn't necessarily true, however - you can generate a self-contained token which the user can use to prove who they are for a fixed length of time, using cryptographic signatures to stop it being forged, rather than having to check it in a central database; this is how JWT (JSON Web Token) works. Importantly, this is not a *session* token - the user should be free to perform a series of requests with the same token, or a series of new tokens, without affecting the results.

The important point is that *the behaviour of the request should depend only on that request*. A stateful API would be saying "product #1 will mean something different depending on which session token you provide"; or  "you must call request X before request Y, and we will track whether you have done so using your session token". In a stateless API, you would say "you must provide a valid product ID to request Y, how you get it is up to you, but probably you will get it by calling request X".

Comment: Does, "_product #1 will mean something different depending on which session token you provide_" necessarily require statefulness? It requires branching logic; but couldn't a stateless JWT token work the same way as in the previous paragraph?

Comment: @jaco0646 No, because two JWT tokens for the same user should be equivalent, you shouldn't need to remember which token you used to search for products in order to buy those products. Perhaps this distinction between authentication and sessions should be clearer.